# how to view image part that is dragged outside canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Is there any procedure to make the part of the image that is dragged outside of the canvas viewable? i.e, I have a canvas in which an image is drawn and can be dragged. While dragging the image part that is crossing the canvas boundaries is not visible. But can it be visible?

Is there any thing to implement such a functionality?

Answer (score 0):

No. The edge of the canvas is, well, the edge of the canvas. I.E., null, void, a black empty space. A vortex.

You would have to have resize the canvas but give the user a smaller view port.